# why are Cubic Bezier functions not accurate compared too windows api PolyBezier?

Tags: c++, graphics, bezier

I have been trying to find a way to draw a curved line/cubic bezier line using a custom function. However, all the examples and such found on the internet, differ a little from each other and usually produce different results, why? . None of the ones i have tried produce the same result as windows api PolyBezier which is what i need.

This is my current code for drawing cubic bezier lines:

```
double Factorial(int number)
{
    double factorial = 1;

    if (number > 1)
    {
        for (int count = 1; count <= number; count++) factorial = factorial * count;
    }

    return factorial;
}

double choose(double a, double b)
{
    return Factorial(a) / (Factorial(b) * Factorial(a - b));
}

VOID MyPolyBezier(HDC hdc, PPOINT Pts, int Total)
{
    float x, y;

    MoveToEx(hdc, Pts[0].x, Pts[0].y, 0);

    Total -= 1;

    //for (float t = 0; t <= 1; t += (1./128.))
    for (float t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.0078125)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        for (int I = 0; I <= Total; I++)
        {
            x += Pts[I].x * choose(Total, I) * pow(1 - t, Total - I) * pow(t, I);
            y += Pts[I].y * choose(Total, I) * pow(1 - t, Total - I) * pow(t, I);
        }
        LineTo(hdc, x, y);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for testing it.

```
POINT TestPts[4];
BYTE TestType[4] = {PT_MOVETO, PT_BEZIERTO, PT_BEZIERTO, PT_BEZIERTO};
//set x, y points for the curved line.
TestPts[0].x = 50;
TestPts[0].y = 200;
TestPts[1].x = 100;
TestPts[1].y = 100;
TestPts[2].x = 150;
TestPts[2].y = 200;
TestPts[3].x = 200;
TestPts[3].y = 200;
//Draw using custom function.
MyPolyBezier(hdc, TestPts, 4);
//Move the curve down some.
TestPts[0].y += 10;
TestPts[1].y += 10;
TestPts[2].y += 10;
TestPts[3].y += 10;
//Draw using windows api.
//PolyDraw(hdc, TestPts, TestType, 4); //PolyDraw gives the same result as PolyBezier.
PolyBezier(hdc, TestPts, 4);
```

And an attached image of my bad results:
Note: the bottom bezier line is windows(PolyBezier) version.

[image: Custom cubic bezier function vs windows PolyBezier]

Edit:
the final goal, Windows(On the left) VS custom funtion. Hopefully this helps in some way.
[image: Windows Vs Custom PolyBezier]

Comment: Beziers can't be plotted directly, since the formula works on a variable `t` which isn't directly correlated with `x` or `y`. It's approximated, and different algorithms will produce different approximations, not to mention rounding effects.

Comment: You subdivide the line into 128 segments and draw linearly between them.  So at those 128 points you should be good -- the lines are noise (your answer is simply wrong between nodes).  Examine those 128 points and see if they are on the windows line: if not, then it means windows is using some other meaning than you.  Half pixel off, a different approximation, rounding -- who knows.  It won't be easy.

Comment: And btw, you mean precise.  Until you find the actual bezier curve and demonstrate how it should be rendered, the above contains no accuracy evidence.  Just two approximations that differ.

Comment: @Yakk The precision i need is the same as windows PolyBezier. I'm loading raw TrueType font data and converting the lines to cubic bezier using windows method found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243285 The functions AppendPolyLineToBezier and AppendQuadBSplineToBezier are the ones doing the converting, I'm currently looking at them, il post if i find something.

Comment: You could try the [Wine implementation](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/gdi32/painting.c) to see if that's closer to how Windows does it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Is this about different APIs drawing what should be the same curve, differently? because the only thing that's going to limit the precision in the curve drawing algorithm is going to be the resolution of the number type used (i.e. 1/int, 32 bit floating point, 64 bit double precision, etc). There's not much point using the choose/pow code when writing quadratic or cubic, the functions are simple enough. `B2(t) = a*(1-t)*(1-t)+2*b*t*(1-t)+c*t*t` and `B3(t) = a*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+3*b*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+3*c*t*t*(1-t)+d*t*t*t`.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I dont see any actual code for drawing bezier curves in your link, its just mask functions that call into an already complied module.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans The question is why are the algorithms different(answered by Mark Ransom), and how to achieve the same precision as windows api PolyBezier(not answered yet/unknown).

Comment: right, so step 1: implement your plotting to use the true functions, not choose() and pow(), and then see whether your code generates the same curvatures. It should, because there's only one way to compute Bezier curves (okay, fine, two. It's a symmetrical function so as a full plot you can start either with terms `t` or `1-t` and the result's the same). Then if it looks too line-segmenty, start increasing your `t` interval precision, say to 0.001 instead of 0.007. Finally: rounding matters. Don't compute your coordinates in INT land. Compute floating point, then round when drawing only.

Comment: @AlwaysNub: Seems to start around line 894?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Oh ok, i did not see that section, i was looking at nulldrv_PolyBezier. I will check it out, but it looks like a slow method... i will have to check it.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I don't understand your equation above, what do the variables B2 and B3 represent, and a, b, c & d represent? srry.

Comment: B2 is the quadratic curve function, B3 the cubic function, a/b/c/d are curve point/control/point coordinates (a/b/c for quadratic, a/b/c/d for cubic) -- http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo

Comment: I haven't investigated your case fully, but I think you might be misinterpreting the points that you retrieve from TTF. It's some time ago that I did this, but I believe that the format skips every second point and that you are supposed to interpolate that point as the middle between two adjacent ones or something similar to that. Also, if you need rendering, check out the FreeType (www.freetype.org) library which you can use to generate vectors or bitmaps and which comes with a relatively permissive license.

Comment: Your sample error indicates your problem is not what you think: differences the size of the top do not lead to the bottom error.  You are probably interpreting line segments as control points to beziers or something.

Comment: @Yakk I don't see how that could be the case, as I'm passing the same x-y points to PolyBezier and MyPolyBezier(Except for adding to all the x points to move the text over when calling MyPolyBezier). Unless i misunderstood what you are saying.

Comment: I am talking about the `AG` -- your version looks like you read some segments as beziers.

Answer (score 0):

So a cubic bezier is a mathematical curve.  The cubic bezier is a specific case of a more general curve.

The cubic bezier is defined by 4 control points -- a start and end point, and 2 control points.  In general, a bezier has n control points in order.

The line is drawn as a time parameter `t` goes from 0 to 1.

To find out where a general bezier of degree `n` is at time `t`:

- For each adjacent pair of control points in your bezier, find the weighted average of them, as controlled by `t`.  So `at + b(1-t)` for control points `a` before `b`.
- Use these `n-1` points to form a degree `n-1` bezier.
- Solve the new bezier at time `t`.

when you hit a degree `1` bezier, stop.  That is your point.

Try writing an algorithm based off the true definition of bezier, and see where it differs from the windows curve.  This may ne less frustrating than taking some approximation and having two sets of errors to reconcile.